# Using voice to give commnands to a plot, is it possible?

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot, simulation, voice-recognition

I will go straight to the point.

I have a plot with a 3D figure represented by points, what I would like to do is give matlab a voice command that make a function starts.

Specifically I would like to say for example "rotate", matlab should recognize this vocal command and make the actual figure in the plot to rotate.

Is this possible or I should give up? Because Im going crazy trying.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it is possible!

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you can do that. Here are the rough steps:

1. Start by recording a very large number of samples of yourself saying "ROTATE", and whatever other commands you'd like to give to the plot.
2. Then use the deep learning functionality from Neural Network Toolbox to train a network on those voice samples, and classify each of them into the appropriate command (you'll need a computer with a decent GPU).
3. Use Data Acquisition Toolbox to connect your sound card, and listen to sounds coming in from your microphone.
4. Connect the audio stream from Data Acquisition Toolbox to the inputs of the network generated in step 2.
5. When the network successfully classifies a portion of the audio stream into one of your commands, execute the appropriate command to rotate, or otherwise modify your plot.

Once you've done all that, apply to MathWorks for a job as an Application Engineer. It would make a nice demo to show to customers.

By the way, all of the above might sound facetious, but is quite serious - this is the sort of thing that MATLAB actually makes pretty easy, and if you know what you're doing I would think it's only maybe a week's work. And I do think that if you showed it in a MathWorks interview, there would be a good chance it might land you a job there.

---

Edit: Or, you could get MATLAB to just make a call to Google's [Cloud Speech API](https://cloud.google.com/speech/) and then do something based on the word it returns. Google are probably better than either of us at neural networks :)

Edit 2: Or, if you're comfortable with a six-hour delay in your command, you could get MATLAB to send an email to [GoTranscript](https://gotranscript.com/), where a real human will transcribe your voice for you, and then MATLAB could read the response email :/